# Map my domain name with my own server

Tags: windows, dns, hosting, windows-server-2008, nameservers

Hi I am having my own domain mydomain.ac.in and i am having my own server (windows 2008) and a Public static IP.

Now i want to host my site in my own server.

Please give me the step by step information to get it done.

Thanks.

Comment: These discussions may look a little bit off topic for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once again tried the steps at http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/dns/setdns and got it right..Now i have updated the name server info at my domain registrar ernet and waiting for it to be updated. Thanks fo the people helped me

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your domain with some DNS hosting service (DNS provider), there is such an astronomic number of these on the web that I do not want to spam the site. [Google](http://www.google.ch/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1&nord=1#hl=en&sugexp=les;&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=hp&qe=RE5TIHByb3ZpZGVy&qesig=OZXWWbAtWjCtP7KPwYPnMA&pkc=AFgZ2tnS3XY3ZV-Nk4zQmhC-MCo3cqrViiMt_HZyJ1wlraAh5VUVp6zwwfnyVe1UDXdmC2M0nJ6jQmDLh1djvxa1Ti1K7SSHpA&cp=12&gs_id=9&xhr=t&q=DNS%20provider&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&tbo=d&nord=1&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=DNS%20provider&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41642243,d.Yms&fp=d25525c5451c0fc7&biw=888&bih=650&ion=1).

Also, collocation center where you keep this server (and from where you have probably obtained that public IP) may also provide DNS services.

From the other side, any computer can be configured as the name server but this will probably not work Internet wide and can be used inside the local network only (combined with DHCP service). If there is an easy way to make this Internet wide, I would also be very interested in, but I doubt.

Your operating system is not much relevant to this question.

Comment: Hi, I registered my domain already in ernet by indian Government and I got my Public Static IP from BSNL India. I hosted my site already and i am able to access my site already using the ip. Now i want to map my domain with the server that i have so that i can access my domain using a domain name. 

I tried the steps in http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/dns/setdns#additional.. But when i add the name server information it says cannot resolve hostname??? that s why i want to know where i am making mistake..

Answer (score 0):

I registered my domain already in ernet by indian Government and I got my Public Static IP from BSNL India. I hosted my site already and i am able to access my site already using the ip. Now i want to map my domain with the server that i have so that i can access my domain using a domain name.

I tried the steps in http://www.hosting.com/support/dedicated/dns/setdns#additional.. But when i add the name server information it says cannot resolve hostname??? that s why i want to know where i am making mistake..