# how do I map my domain name to an ZK application in TOMCAT server?

Tags: java, tomcat, mapping, zk

We have developed `ZK Application` and hosted in `windows 2000 server`. It works fine outside the server by the url `http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:8081/xxxxxx/login.zul`

We have also registered our own domain as `www.xxxx.com`. Now we need to map this domain to our application.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: Urgh dude your domain provider should have tools allowing you to map the IP to the domain...

Comment: I guess for it to be publicly available you would have to edit your DNS settings with whoever hosts this information.  E.g ZoneEdit, EasyDNS etc

Comment: Is there any role of APACHAE SERVER HERE

Comment: No, Apache has nothing to do with this. As others have said, DNS will let to map the readable name to an IP. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598557/map-my-domain-name-with-my-own-server

Answer (score 0):

What you needs is configurate your public ip (if you have it) in a domain nameserver(dns). And last in domain panel configurate your nameserver(ns) to the domain.

The dns server is responsable of translate your ip in a domain. http://www.petri.co.il/install_and_configure_w2k_dns_server.htm

Regards